# Android Sqlite update does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been having a weird issue lately regarding my database-driven android app. I use the code UPDATE before with no problem but now it won't allow me to update changes to my records.

I did try to log if it's saving the changes I've made but it doesn't.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void initControls() {

    userInput = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    save = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btSave);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btCancel);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        stID = extras.getString("dog_id");
        dog_name = extras.getString("dog_name");
        cursor = dbHelper.fetchbBreedByName(dog_name);

        strDesc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
        Log.d("Animal ID", "Animal ID is " + stID + " and breed is " + dog_name);
        userInput.setText(strDesc);
    }

}

private void checkDatabaseConnection() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    try {
            dbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
    }

   }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btSave:
        if(userInput.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }
        else {
            id = Long.valueOf(stID);
            dbHelper.updateDescription( id, userInput.getText().toString() );
            Toast.makeText(this, "Description has been updated successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            strDesc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
            Log.d("Updated", dog_name + " " + strDesc);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DogClass.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btCancel:
        userInput.setText("");
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    dbHelper.close(); // close DB
    cursor.close(); // close cursor
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

[Whole code can be viewed here](http://pastebin.com/wLZyu5Ag)

I really don't know what's wrong, anybody here has experienced this before? Might as well help me figure out what I'm missing in my code. Help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is wrong?

Comment: The changes I made does not update. I did print the result in the Log but it's saying my changes are not updated.

Comment: Seems like you expect a cursor row to update when the underlying data changes. That's not true, you'll have to re-query to see the database changes.

Comment: Can you give me sample codes to requery the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use update method like this..

```
 SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
 cv.put(IConstants.FOLDER_LOCKED, isSelected);
 database.update(FOLDER_TABLE, cv, IConstants.FOLDER_NAME + "= ?",
 new String[] { foldername });
```